# Why is this C function returning int values in two's complement?

Tags: c, simd, inline-assembly, twos-complement, mmx

I'm using a library that uses Intel's MMX single instruction, multiple data (SIMD) instruction set to speed up the multiplication of integer arrays. The function I am using contains in-line assembly to use the MMX SIMD registers in Intel processors and perform the multiplication.

After multiplying two integer arrays with the function, I receive an array that contains incorrect values for integers that should be negative.  However, when converting these values to binary, I notice the integers are representing the correct value in 2's complement.  The integers should be, and are, 16 bits long.

Even stranger is when two negative integers are multiplied, as opposed to one positive one negative, the function returns an integer value that, when converted to binary, adds an extra bit as the most significant bit (tags additional bit onto left hand side of the binary number). That bit's value is 1, but if you ignore that bit, the rest of the bits correctly display the expected value.

It's hard to say in words so let me give an example:

I have three int arrays A, B, and C.

A = {-1, 4, 1, -1, 1, -2, -3, 7},

B = {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1}

C = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}

When A and B are multiplied together, I would expect

{1, -4, -1, 1, -1, 2, 3, 7}

to be stored in C.

However after using the library's function, I get

{65537, 65532, 65535, 65537, 65535, 65538, 65539, 7}

as my values for C.

The first value, 65537, in binary is 10000000000000001.  Without the extra 17th bit, this would equal 1, but even so, the value should just be 1, not 65537.  The second value, 65532, in binary is 1111111111111100 which is 2's complement for -4.  This is well and good but why isn't that value just -4.  Also notice the last value, 7.  When negative signs are not involved, the function gives a value in the expected form.

The in-line assembly is written for compilation on Microsoft Visual Studio but I'm using intel's c/c++ compiler with -use-msasm flag.

Here is the function code:

```
void mmx_mul(void *A, void *B, void *C, int cnt)
{

int cnt1;
int cnt2;
int cnt3;

cnt1 = cnt / 32;
cnt2 = (cnt - (32*cnt1)) / 4;
cnt3 = (cnt - (32*cnt1) - (4*cnt2));


__asm
{

    //; Set up for loop
    mov edi, A; // Address of A source1
    mov esi, B; // Address of B source2
    mov ebx, C; // Address of C dest
    mov ecx, cnt1;  // Counter
    jecxz ZERO;

    L1:

        movq mm0, [edi];        //Load from A
        movq mm1, [edi+8];      //Load from A
        movq mm2, [edi+16];     //Load from A
        movq mm3, [edi+24];     //Load from A
        movq mm4, [edi+32];     //Load from A
        movq mm5, [edi+40];     //Load from A
        movq mm6, [edi+48];     //Load from A
        movq mm7, [edi+56];     //Load from A

        pmullw mm0, [esi];      //Load from B & multiply B * (A*C)
        pmullw mm1, [esi+8];    //Load from B & multiply B * (A*C)
        pmullw mm2, [esi+16];   //Load from B & multiply B * (A*C)
        pmullw mm3, [esi+24];   //Load from B & multiply B * (A*C)
        pmullw mm4, [esi+32];   //Load from B & multiply B * (A*C)
        pmullw mm5, [esi+40];   //Load from B & multiply B * (A*C)
        pmullw mm6, [esi+48];   //Load from B & multiply B * (A*C)
        pmullw mm7, [esi+56];   //Load from B & multiply B * (A*C)

        movq [ebx],    mm0;     //Store C = A*B
        movq [ebx+8],  mm1;     //Store C = A*B
        movq [ebx+16], mm2;     //Store C = A*B
        movq [ebx+24], mm3;     //Store C = A*B
        movq [ebx+32], mm4;     //Store C = A*B
        movq [ebx+40], mm5;     //Store C = A*B
        movq [ebx+48], mm6;     //Store C = A*B
        movq [ebx+56], mm7;     //Store C = A*B

        add edi, 64;
        add esi, 64;
        add ebx, 64;

    loop L1;                            // Loop if not done

ZERO:

    mov ecx, cnt2;
    jecxz ZERO1;

    L2:

        movq mm1, [edi];        //Load from A
        pmullw mm1, [esi];      //Load from B & multiply B * (A*C)
        movq [ebx], mm1;
        add edi, 8;
        add esi, 8;
        add ebx, 8;

    loop L2;

ZERO1:

    mov ecx, cnt3;
    jecxz ZERO2;

    mov eax, 0;


    L3:                             //Really finish off loop with non SIMD instructions

        mov eax, [edi];
        imul eax, [esi];
        mov [ebx], ax;
        add esi, 2;
        add edi, 2;
        add ebx, 2;

    loop L3;

ZERO2:

    EMMS;

}


}
```

and an example of me calling it.

```
int A[8] = {-1, 4, 1, -1, 1, -2, -3, 7};
int B[8] = {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1};
int C[8];
mmx_mul(A, B, C, 16);
```

The last argument 16 is the number of total elements in A and B combined.

The library I am using is free-use and can be found at https://www.ngs.noaa.gov/gps-toolbox/Heckler.htm

Comment: FYI [the `loop` instruction is slow on all CPUs other than AMD Bulldozer / Ryzen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35742570/why-is-the-loop-instruction-slow-couldnt-intel-have-implemented-it-efficiently).  i.e. it's slow on all CPUs when MMX was still relevant, so whoever wrote this code didn't know how to optimize properly.  Most compilers should give good results from auto-vectorizing `C[i] = A[i] * B[i]` with SSE2, AVX2, or AVX512 (for wider versions of `pmullw`).

Comment: https://www.ngs.noaa.gov/gps-toolbox/Heckler/Readme.txt contains very important note `Truncate C to a 16 bit signed integer, preserving sign bit C(0:14) = C(0:14), C(15) = C(31)` it looks like you should perform this truncation by yourself

Comment: @llya Bursov Truncating myself corrected the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pmullw` multiplies packed integer *words* (16-bit elements in Intel terminology).  `int` is a 32-bit type, you need SSE4.1 `pmulld` (packed dword) for that (or some shuffling with SSE2 `pmuludq` to only keep the low half of each 64-bit result).

> and an example of me calling it.
>
> ```
> int A[8] = {-1, 4, 1, -1, 1, -2, -3, 7};
> ```

You passed it 32-bit integers, but you already said you know it wants 16-bit integers.  (`int` is a 32-bit type in all the major 32 and 64-bit x86 calling conventions / ABIs).  **This is what happens when you use `void*` and get the types wrong.**

Your `65537` from `-1` and `-1` is easy to explain:  it's 2^16 + 1, i.e. `0x001001`, from two packed 16-bit `-1 * -1 = 1`.  You have `-1 * -1` in the most-significant (upper) 16-bit element of most of your the 32-bit elements.

The 16-bit `pmullw` instruction effectively treats your input data as arrays of `short` (or `unsigned short`, because that's the same binary operation):

```
// 32-bit value -1 = 0xFFFFFFFF       4                   1
short A[] = { 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF,   0x0004, 0x0000,     0x0001, 0x0000, ... }
// 32-bit value:   -1,               -1,                 -1
short B[] = { 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF,   0xFFFF, 0xFFFF,     0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, ... }


short C:      0x0001, 0x0001,   0xFFFC,  0,         0xFFFF, 0
// 32-bit value: 0x00010001      0x0000FFFC         0x0000FFFF
//                    65537,          65532,             65535,
```

x86 is little-endian, so the least-significant word comes first.  I've shown the word and dword values in normal place-value order as a single hex number, *not* in the byte-order they appear in memory as separate hex bytes.  This is why the first (in memory) word of a double-word `int` is the low 16 bits of the `int` value.

See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement for more background on the bit-representations of signed integer numbers on x86 (and essentially all other modern CPU architectures).

---

FYI [the `loop` instruction is slow on all CPUs other than AMD Bulldozer / Ryzen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35742570/why-is-the-loop-instruction-slow-couldnt-intel-have-implemented-it-efficiently).  i.e. it's slow on all CPUs when MMX was still relevant, so whoever wrote this code didn't know how to optimize properly.

**Most compilers should give good results from auto-vectorizing `C[i] = A[i] * B[i]`** with SSE2, AVX2, or AVX512 (for wider versions of `pmullw`).  Using inline-asm at all is not a good idea, and using badly-optimized *MMX* asm is an even worse idea, unless you actually need to run this on a Pentium III or something else that doesn't have SSE2.

Comment: What do you mean by "You have `-1 * -1` in the most-significant (upper) 16-bit element of most of your the 32-bit elements"?

Comment: @JakeJohnson: every 32-bit element is composed of a high/low pair of 16-bit elements.  32-bit 2's complement `-1` is `0xffffffff`, which is also 16-bit 2's complement `{-1, -1}`.

Comment: Ok so are you saying when I get `65537`, I'm really getting two 16-bit elements: `{0x001, 0x001}`?  But why don't I just get `{0x000, 0x001} = 1`? Does `{-1, -1}` translate to `-1 * -1`?  I don't understand why it would.  Can you also explain why I get `65535` instead of `1` when multiplying `-1` and `1`?  I think that would help clarify.

Comment: @JakeJohnson: updated my answer with a more detailed example.